# Help identifying resistor

Tags: resistors

Hi I'm having trouble identifying this resistor with the color code. It's for a GK backline 600 300w bass head, the schematic calls for two 10 2w resistor ran in parallel. But I can't find it anywhere only  the 10 1/2 or 1/2w resistors.

[image]

Comment: What does it measure as?

Comment: Looks toasty. Do you by "two 10 2 W" mean two 10 ohm 2 W resistors?

Answer (score 3):

Brown Black Black Black = 10 ohm +/- 20%. I believe that's all you're asking?

Comment: 20% resistors traditionally didn't have a tolerance band - they would only have the three bands for value.  I think that this component is too well cooked to have any faith in the apparent colour code.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit on the left is using 10 ohm 2W resistor, effectively 5 ohm 4W.
Circuit on the right uses 10 ohm 0.5W resistor, effectively 5 ohm 4W.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGh5tX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>